# toString(); No imprime el ciclo. Como puedo hacer para imprimir las celdas true con el metodo toString?

Tags: java, bucle-for

> Buenas tardes. He creado un arreglo boolean y he hecho que en los índices insertados la celda se torne true.  Lo que pretendo es que el método toString imprima el índice de la celda en la que el valor es true y "---" en aquellas en las que es false. Le he dado 7 vueltas pero no lo logro...Gracias

```
public class TestBooleana {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Booleana one = new Booleana(1, 18, 23, 45, 47, 79, 12);
        System.out.println(one.toString());
    }

}
```

**class Booleana**

```
class Booleana{

    int talla = 100;
    boolean[] enteros = new boolean[talla];

    public Booleana(int... num) {
        for(int a: num)
            insertar(a);
    }  

    public void insertar(int a) {
        if(a < talla) enteros[a] = true;
    }


    public String toString() {

        for(int i = 0; i < enteros.length; i++) { 
            if(enteros[i] == true) return i + " ";
        }
        return "---";

    }

}
```

Comment: Ten cuidado, porque podrias estar sobreescribiendo al metodo existente toString, deberias llamar a tu metodo toString de otra manera, por ejemplo toStringBoolean.

Comment: Podrias mostrar tu salida actual, y la salida que realemente queres?

Comment: @gbianchi la salida actual es "1", es decir el índice del primer elemento en el que la celda es true. La salida que pretendo es (1, 18, 23, 45, 47, 79, 12), que son todos los índices dónde los valores de las celdas se tornan true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas, el primero es que en tu método insertar, aquello que no cumpla tu condición no le estas asignando nada, en tu caso de acuerdo a tu lógica el valor insertado si no se cumple la condición debería ser `false`, así que esta parte de tu código:

```
public void insertar(int a) {
    if(a < talla) enteros[a] = true;
}
```

Pasaria a verse como:

```
public void insertar(int a) {
    //Eso se conoce como shorthand if...
    enteros[a] = a < talla ? true : false;
}
```

Con esto, nos vamos a tu metodo `toString`, donde el problema es que estas intentando concatenar a la vez que retornas valores, lo cual por supuesto no funcionara.

Debes tener en cuenta algo:

- La sentencia return rompe los ciclos y también la función, por lo que apenas se llegue al return aquello que este después del return no sera ejecutado y la función terminara su ejecución.

La solución a ello es crear un `String` aparte, el cual sera el que devolvamos al final en la funcion, **sin usar return dentro del ciclo**.

Entonces tu metodo `toString` pasa a verse asi:

```
public String toString() {

    String result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < enteros.length; i++) { 
        result = enteros[i] ? result + (i + " ") : result + " --- ";
    }

    return result;

}
```

Con esto ya funcionaria, tener en cuenta que el shorthand if:

```
result = enteros[i] ? result + (i + " ") : result + " --- ";
```

Es enrealidad es una asignacion corta dependiendo de condicionales, donde el caracter `?` representa a `if` y el caracter `:` representa a `else`, no hay representación directa de `else if` en un shorthand if.

Aquello que se cumpla sera lo que será asignado como valor a la variable.

Otro error que tienes es este de aquí:

```
public Booleana(int... num) {
    for(int a: num)
        insertar(a);
}
```

No digo que sea incorrecto, porque en algunos lenguajes de programación se puede omitir los `{}`, pero a mi si no los ponia me daba resultados extraños asi que tuve que ponerselos al `for`:

```
public Booleana(int... num) {
    for(int a : num){
        insertar(a);
    }
}
```

Entonces tu codigo completo corregido (he juntado las clases en un mismo sitio solo para pruebas), se vería así:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static class Booleana{

        int talla = 100;
        boolean[] enteros = new boolean[talla];

        public Booleana(int... num) {
            for(int a : num){
                insertar(a);
            }
        }  

        public void insertar(int a) {
            //Eso se conoce como shorthand if...
            enteros[a] = a < talla ? true : false;
        }


        public String toString() {

            String result = "";

            for(int i = 0; i < enteros.length; i++) { 
                result = enteros[i] ? result + (i + " ") : result + " --- ";
            }

            return result;

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Booleana one = new Booleana(1, 18, 23, 45, 47, 79, 12);
        System.out.println(one.toString());

    }
}
```

He decidido poner el código completo junto al final para poder compararlo con las ediciones hechas a tu código y que no nos perdamos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo he modificado pero la salida que da ahora es "false ---".

Comment: Ohhh ya entiendo por que pasa... ya lo arreglo.

Comment: Listo, editado, ahora deberia funcionar, por cierto, mira la parte final, quiza entiendas o veas mejor los cambios realizados al ver la parte final.

Comment: Riven@esta si funciona. Ya había encontrado otra solución pero esto que has escrito ilustra un poco mejor las dudas que albergo acerca del toString y la orden return. Mil gracias